# Relational Algebra and Domain Relational Calculus for SQL Query

Tags: sql, rdbms, relational-algebra, domain-calculus

Tables:

```
Contest(starter, ender, pointsStarter, pointsEnder, debatedate)
Debater(name, club, age)
```

Query:

Give all contest details of contests where the starting debater is a member
of the "Plato" club and prevented his opponent from scoring any points.

SQL I have written:

```
SELECT starter, pointsStarter, ender, pointsEnder, debatedate
FROM contest
WHERE pointsEnder = 0
AND starter IN (SELECT name FROM debater WHERE club = 'Plato')
```

Relational Algebra I have written:

```
Π starter,ender,pointsStarter,pointsEnder,debatedate (
    Ϭ Contest.pointsEnder=0 (
        Ϭ club=”Plato” (Contest Debater)))
```

Domain Relational Calculus I have written:

```
{< starter,ender,pointsStarter,pointsEnder,debatedate> | 
    Ǝ < starter,ender,pointsStarter,pointsEnder,debatedate > ϵ Contest (
        Ǝ < name,club,age > ϵ Debater (
            ^ pointsEnder=0 ^ club=”Plato”))
}
```

Comment: I would like to know if the relational algebra and domain calculus are right answers to the query

Comment: Please edit your question, comments are not for clarifications, and are ephemeral. Also please give a reference to what algebra & calculus variants you are supposed to use, because there are many. Also if you want more than a yes or no you should justify your work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparent typos: There is an errant `^` before pointsEnder in your calculus. You presumably intended a join between `Contest` & `Debater` in your algebra.

You haven't given a reference to the versions of the algebra & calculus that you are to use. So we can only guess the likely nature of corrections. It's unlikely you need `Contest.`.

Note your algebra & calculus haven't equated starter & name. If your join is natural, you need to rename `name` to `starter` around `Debater`. Your innermost calculus needs an added conjunct that equates them.

You don't want to drop the result columns via:

```
Π starter,ender,pointsStarter,pointsEnder,debatedate (...)
```

You want to drop the non-result columns. If your join is natural that's:

```
Π club, age (...)
```

Similarly the result columns of a calculus query have to appear free (not quantified by Ǝ) in the right hand side expression. So instead of:

```
Ǝ < ... > ϵ Contest (...)
```

you need something like:

```
Ǝ < s,e,ps,pe,dd > ϵ Contest (
        s=starter ^ e=ender ^ ps=pointsStarter ^ pe=pointsEnder ^ dd=debatedate
    ^   ...)
```